# Expression sequencing in GLSL: what happens with postincrement

Tags: glsl, post-increment, sequence-points

In C/C++ there are clear rules defining "sequence points"/"sequenced before" relation, so e.g. the following expressions

```
int k = i-- * i;
int p = j-- + --j;
```

invoke undefined behavior.

Now, I'm wondering what are the rules governing such expressions in GLSL. I couldn't find anything in The OpenGL Shading Language (4.40) spec that defines a concept similar to sequence points/sequenced before relation.

In section "5.9 Expressions" it only says

> Preincrement and pre-decrement add or subtract 1 or 1.0 to the contents of the expression they operate on and the value of the pre-increment or pre-decrement expression is the resulting value of that modification. Post-increment and post-decrement expressions add or subtract 1 or 1.0 to the contents of the expression they operate on, but the resulting expression has the expression’s value before the post-increment or post-decrement was executed.

but there is no mention of when the postincrementation should actually happen with relation to e.g. other subexpressions.

1/ Is there any specification or agreement on how sequencing of expressions is defined in GLSL?

2/ Is `i-- * ++i` a valid/well-defined GLSL expression? If it is, what is its value when at the beginning we had `i=1`?